# Google Sheets Apps Script "Service Spreadsheets timed out while accessing document"

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

We aren't programmers so we had to cobble together a Google Sheets Apps Script by trial & error, and the script is causing our Sheet to crash dozens of times per day now. We have read that we need to adjust it slightly to apply to the whole sheet rather than just apply to columns and rows, but we don't understand how to accomplish that so we were hoping that those of you who understand scripts could help us.

The script simply copies existing (very basic) formulas down to any new row that is added automatically so our staff doesn't have to drag formulas down manually.

The script that we are using is this:

```
function FillFormulas() {   

var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('2021-2023');   

var lastRow = spreadsheet.getLastRow();   

spreadsheet.getRange("F2").setFormula("=E2*0.961-0.3");   
var fillDownRange = spreadsheet.getRange(2,6,(lastRow-1));   spreadsheet.getRange("F2").copyTo(fillDownRange); 

spreadsheet.getRange("I2").setFormula("=((F2-G2)-H2)");   
var fillDownRange = spreadsheet.getRange(2,9,(lastRow-1));   spreadsheet.getRange("I2").copyTo(fillDownRange); 

spreadsheet.getRange("J2").setFormula("=I2/E2");   
var fillDownRange = spreadsheet.getRange(2,10,(lastRow-1));   spreadsheet.getRange("J2").copyTo(fillDownRange);

spreadsheet.getRange("N2").setFormula("=HYPERLINK(CONCATENATE(\"https://nomadicsupply.com/wp-admin/post.php?post=\",B2,\"&action=edit\"),B2)");   
var fillDownRange = spreadsheet.getRange(2,14,(lastRow-1));   spreadsheet.getRange("N2").copyTo(fillDownRange); 

}
```

When it fails it says: "Service Spreadsheets timed out while accessing document" and then all of the formatting in our sheet is broken; font sizes and columns formatting such as "Number: Percent" all break.

The only way to resolve it is to manually reformat all of the affected columns manually after it crashes.

Does anyone know what might make this script run properly so it doesn't time out and crash the document? We read every post that asks this question but we don't understand how to apply those answers about "getRange" to our particular script.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In order to apply a formula in a whole column, please use this logic:

EDIT: added all the formulas

```
function FillFormulas() {   

  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('2021-2023');

  spreadsheet.getRange("F2:F").setFormula(`=INDIRECT("E"&ROW())*0.961-0.3`);
  spreadsheet.getRange("I2:I").setFormula(`=((INDIRECT("F"&ROW())-INDIRECT("G"&ROW()))-INDIRECT("H"&ROW()))`); 
  spreadsheet.getRange("J2:J").setFormula(`=INDIRECT("I"&ROW())/INDIRECT("E"&ROW())`);
  spreadsheet.getRange("N2:N").setFormula(`=HYPERLINK(CONCATENATE(\"https://nomadicsupply.com/wp-admin/post.php?post=\",INDIRECT("B"&ROW()),\"&action=edit\"))`);

}
```

`getRange("F2:F")` -> Get all cells in column F, starting from row 2 [getRange(A1notation)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet?getrangea1notation)

`INDIRECT()` -> In order to concatenate column and row, and keep it dynamic (ex: "F2") [GSHEET INDIRECT()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093377)

`"E"&ROW()` -> Get dynamic row and concatenate with column [GSHEET ROW()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093316)

Regarding your crashs, there might be a correlation with a problem reported here : https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/282113264

Comment: Thank you!

We tried to figure this out and now it says:

Syntax error: SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input line: 19 file: Code.gs

spreadsheet.getRange("N2:N").setFormula(`=INDIRECT("N"&ROW())HYPERLINK(CONCATENATE(\"https://nomadicsupply.com/wp-admin/post.php?post=\",B2,\"&action=edit\"),B2)');
var fillDownRange = spreadsheet.getRange(2,14,(lastRow-1));   spreadsheet.getRange("N2").copyTo(fillDownRange);

}

Comment: Upon testing we now get this in every row:

#ERROR! #ERROR!
#ERROR! #ERROR!
#ERROR! #ERROR!
#ERROR! #ERROR!
#ERROR! #ERROR!
#ERROR! #ERROR!
#ERROR! #ERROR!
#ERROR! #ERROR!
#ERROR! #ERROR!
#ERROR! #ERROR!
#ERROR! #ERROR!
#ERROR! #ERROR!
#ERROR! #ERROR!
#ERROR! #ERROR!

Comment: I updated my answer with all the formula. Please stricly copy/paste my code in order to make it work. You don't need the `copyTo` function line. And please watch carefully the syntax with quote / double quote / backtick

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH for your help with this! 

The first 3 formulas worked but the formula that creates a link to our order on our website in the last column just shows a URL now instead of an order number. Before now the last column showed the order number from column B as a link to our website.

Screenshot here: https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/40594851?key=75e62f087a816a37992413be754bb76c

Do you think there's an easier way to just have the order number that's already in column A be converted to a link rather than having a whole new column (N) be the link?

Comment: Unfortunately this script has crashed our sheet 6 times today, so it's still not going to work unfortunately. Apparently Google Sheets can't handle the script.

Comment: As mentioned in my answer, a bug is reported to Google that might be related to your situation.